# How do I format JSON data to display correctly with Google Charts?

Tags: ajax, json, google-visualization

Here's my code, I've spent hours and hours Google searching this with no success...

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization(){
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "FinancialData.php",
    //    data: "ChartRequest=" + "Employees",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false, 
          }).responseText;
          window.alert(jsonData); //this always returns correctly formatted data

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData); //this never works


    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {title:"Progress Fest Financial Information, Fall 2013"});
};
```

Code returns "Table has no columns"

Comment: It's not related, but you should not do `async: false`.

Answer (score 1):

`responseText` is the response as a string, not parsed by JSON into a Javascript object. jQuery passes the parsed result to the AJAX completion function, but you're not using that, so you don't get it. You need to call `$.parseJSON` explicitly:

```
var jsonData = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
    ...
}).responseText);
```

Or you can use the completion function (so you don't need to use `async: false`):

```
$.ajax({
    ...
}).done(function(jsonData) {
    window.alert(jsonData);
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {title:"Progress Fest Financial Information, Fall 2013"});
});
```

Comment: I tried both of those codes. There are no errors but it still says "Table has no columns."  Could it be related to the JSON I'm making in the .php file? "[
    {
        "Employees": "Security",
        "Cash": "40.00"
    },
    {
        "Employees": "Sound",
        "Cash": "45.00"
    },
    {
        "Employees": "Lighting",
        "Cash": "0"
    },
    {
        "Employees": "Photographer",
        "Cash": "30.00"
    }
]"

Comment: @user, Did you check the rules on how to format datatable objects? Your output doesn't seem to match the format explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable).